# Can you bring aerosol bug spray for ants on a plane from Portugal to Canada?

Tags: luggage, canada, airlines, portugal, prohibited-items

Can you bring aerosol bug spray for ants from Portugal to Canada in your checked luggage?

Comment: No, I think you can easily buy it at your destination

Answer (score 5):

## No

You should check your airline's rules to know for certain, but for instance, [TAP Portugal](https://www.flytap.com/en-gb/baggage/forbidden-baggage) says:

> The transport by air of dangerous articles is not permitted, such as: [...]    Toxic – (insecticides or pesticides);

I strongly suspect that other airlines will be similar.

Anyway, such products should be readily available in Canada, so it would likely be much easier to buy it after you arrive.